# If I use the bridge, how effective is it if I am living in a remote location in South America?

Tags: configuration

It is unlikely that there are many or any Tor users nearby.

Comment: What do you mean by effective and what risks do you have in mind? Please elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 1):

All Tor nodes are public except bridge relays. Your ISP won't know you are using Tor with bridges if that's what you mean.